# try catch on javaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, json

I have a code for reading a json file in JS. I had the code wrapped in "try catch" blocks.
The way I get it - if the file is not found for some reason, it should enter the "catch" block.
Yet, if "lang" is undefined - it throws a 404:
" GET --<-server->--/settings/Lang_undefined.json 404 (Not Found) "
without ever entering the "catch" block.

can anyone help me understand why it is so?

Thank you!!

```
function loadDic() {
    try {
        $.getJSON(SERVER_URL + "settings/Lang_" + lang + ".json", function(data) {
            dic = data["dictionary"];
            setLanguage();
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error happens long after `loadDic` is done, outside of the try/catch.

Comment: It probably works just as expected, but ajax is asynchronous so the try/catch block will not catch network errors or other things during the request.

Comment: http error codes don't throw exceptions

Comment: Thank you very much! So what can i do to catch an file not found exception?

Comment: "It *throws* a 404"? How are you concluding that any of this code is actually *throwing an exception*?

Comment: I may not be quite accurate on the terminology, but you know what i meant. I get a 404 on the console

Comment: Sure, you get a 404 on the console. But that's not an exception because no exception is *thrown* here which could be *caught*.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be making an ajax request (not a jsonp request,) you can catch the error using the error callback.

```
function loadDic() {
    $.getJSON(SERVER_URL + "settings/Lang_" + lang + ".json", function(data) {
        dic = data["dictionary"];
        setLanguage();
    }).fail(setLanguageFail);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this, and i get to the "fail" part. yet I  can still see the 404 in the console. Is that ok? Will it not cause problems with the program?

Comment: Yes, that's ok, and you cant avoid it other than by not requesting a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous.

1. The `getJSON` function sends an HTTP request.
2. It sends it successfully
3. The `try` is successful
4. The Ajax then gets a response saying that the server had a 404 error
5. You haven't specified an error event handler, so nothing happens

The 404 error does not cause an exception to be thrown (it is an HTTP error, not a JavaScript error) and there is nothing waiting to catch an exception at that time anyway.

If you want to do something in the event of an error, then specify a function to handle it (you can't do this with `getJSON()`, you should use `ajax()` instead). Note that you cannot return (based on this) from the function that included the `getJSON` call.